# Make a Views with Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

I want to create views programmatically, Matrix: 10X10 = 100 views . I've created IB but it has to be programmed with Xcode. How can i do this?

For one view create this, for 10X10 views I don't know. How can i do all views;

```
UIView *tempView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 660, 60, 60)];
                    [self.view addSubview:tempView1];
                    rd = 0;
                    gr = 0.5;
                    bl =0;           
                    tempView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rd green:gr blue:bl alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfViewsHorizontally; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < amountOfViewsVertically; j++) 
    {
        UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i*widthOfView), (j*heightOfView), widthOfView, heightOfView)];
        rd = 0;
        gr = 0.5;
        bl =0;          
        someView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rd green:gr blue:bl alpha:1.0];

        UILabel *someLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        someLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,20); //this will add a label in all the upperleft corners (point(0,0)) of every view with width 50 and height 20.
        [someView addSubView:someLabel];

        //[someViewArray addObject:someView]; //add view to an array
        [self.view addSubview:someView];
    }
}
```

You might want to put them into some sort of array so you can access them at some later point.

---

If you want components like UILabel to be added to those views. You will have to use the intern coordinate system of those views.

Comment: You are welcome^^ Don't forget to upvote/accept answers that are usefull to you.

Comment: in addition , i want to Label inside to views  i used  someLabel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i*widthOfView), 630 + (j*heightOfView), 50, 20)];  but cant see any label:(

Comment: The UILabels you are trying to add use the coordinate system of the view you add them in. someLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)]; should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of more detailed layout, row, height dynamically, check out [my article here](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/keeping-things-simple-the-dynamic-box-model/). It shows how you can not only dynamically layout boxes according to size and screen size but also how dynamic reordering works.

See the article for more details but the key approach is...

```
- (void) layoutBoxesWithRowCount:(NSInteger)rowCount {
  double xPos = kBoxSpacer;
  double yPos = kBoxSpacer;
  int boxCount = 0;

  for(LOBox *box in boxes) {
    CGRect frame = [box frame];
    frame.origin.x = xPos;
    frame.origin.y = yPos;
    [box setFrame:frame];

    xPos += kBoxDimension + kBoxSpacer;
    boxCount++;

    if(boxCount == rowCount) {
        boxCount = 0;
        xPos = kBoxSpacer;
        yPos += kBoxDimension + kBoxSpacer;
    }
  }
}
```

Full write-up [here.](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/keeping-things-simple-the-dynamic-box-model/)